# How to Check is email exists or not in python

Tags: python, email, smtp

I want to check that the given email id is really exists or not in smtp server. Is it possible to check or not.? If it possible please give me suggestion how can we do it.

Comment: http://verify-email.org/

Comment: If you are using smtplib module of python then you can use its smtp.verify(address) method to check whether the email address is valid or not. https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/smtplib.html

Answer (score 0):

Short of sending an email and having someone respond to it is impossible to verify an email exists.

You can verify the SMTP server has a whois address, but thats it.